# C# Model List setting returned null

Tags: c#

I have a simple model class as below

```
public class IndivudualDetail
{
   public string Address1 { get; set; }
   public string City { get; set; }
}

public class ListDetails
{
    public List<IndivudualDetail> itemlist { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller, am trying to build the model as below

```
ListDetails listDetails = new ListDetails();
foreach (var item in Items)
{
    IndivudualDetail indivudualDetail = new IndivudualDetail
    {
        Address1 = item.Address1,
        City = item.City
    };
    listDetails.itemlist.Add(indivudualDetail);
}
```

I am getting "**listDetails.itemlist.get returned null.**"

what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You never init `itemlist`, see the link above.

Comment: I tried the example from the above link as Person p1 = new Person();
            p1.Books.Add(new Book { Title = "title1" });
            p1.Books.Add(new Book { Title = "title2" });  still am object reference error

Comment: my model class is   public class Book
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
        
    }

Comment: Yes, the post says that the code will also throw a NRE, because the collection was not initialized.

Comment: Got it and it works I have initiated the list.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize list of IndivudualDetail before adding to list
Use this

```
 ListDetails listDetails = new ListDetails(itemlist = new List<IndivudualDetail>() );
foreach (var item in Items)
{
   IndivudualDetail indivudualDetail = new IndivudualDetail
   {
     Address1 = item.Address1,
     City = item.City
};

listDetails.itemlist.Add(indivudualDetail);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to create the list too

```
public class ListDetails
{
    public List<IndivudualDetail> itemlist { get; set; }
    ListDetails(){
        item:List = new List<IndivudualDetail>();
    }
}
```